# Is `gcloud storage` billing us for transfers of public data?

Tags: gcloud, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

We're switching over our scripts from using `gsutil` to the reportedly faster `gcloud storage`. However we access a significant amount of public data, for example from `gs://gcp-public-data--broad-references`.

We do NOT want to pay to download this public data. However it appears that `gcloud storage` is automatically setting the `X-Goog-User-Project` header for public transfers while `gsutil` does not.

Is my understanding of the various documentation correct that `glcoud storage` is instructing GCS to bill us and not the public bucket for transfers?

1. Run `gcloud version`

   - On my machine this outputs `Google Cloud SDK 407.0.0` and `gsutil 5.15`
2. Run `gcloud init`

   - Log in
   - Select a google project
3. Run `gcloud config list`

   - Verify the project you selected before has been configured
4. Run `gsutil -d ls gs://gcp-public-data--broad-references`

   - Verify that the request `Headers:` do NOT contain `X-Goog-User-Project`
5. Run `gcloud --log-http storage ls gs://gcp-public-data--broad-references`

   - Verify that under `== headers start ==` your default project has been included as the `X-Goog-User-Project`

According to all the documentation I've been able to find one should not set that header by default.

Via https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/requester-pays:

> Important: Buckets that have Requester Pays disabled still accept requests that include a billing project, and charges are applied to the billing project supplied in the request. Consider any billing implications prior to including a billing project in all of your requests.

Via https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgooguserproject:

> The project specified in the header is billed for charges associated with the request. This header is used, for example, when making requests to buckets that have Requester Pays enabled.

---

Bonus:

1. Run `gsutil ls gs://gnomad-public-requester-pays`

   - You should receive an error `BadRequestException: 400 Bucket is a requester pays bucket but no user project provided.`
2. Run `gcloud storage ls gs://gnomad-public-requester-pays`

   - The bucket contents should be listed

The latter above doesn't seem correct to me as I never intentionally told `gcloud storage` which project to bill for the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This behavior seems to have been fixed as of the Google Cloud  SDK 411.0.0 released 2022-12-06. As of that version running the setup specified in the original question no longer sends the `X-Goog-User-Project` header.

Thanks @carbocation for the heads up about the fix!

---

Heard back from a support member after this was reposted to the Google Cloud Community Forums.

[ErnestoC said](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Is-gcloud-storage-billing-us-for-transfers-of-public-data/m-p/485977/highlight/true#M1627):

> The [default behavior](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#:%7E:text=billing-,quota_project,-The%20Google%20Cloud) of the Cloud CLI gcloud is to use the current project for all quota and billing operations. This is why you automatically see your project ID passed in X-Goog-User-Project. This behavior can be overridden though by adding the global [--billing-project](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--billing-project) flag to any command.
>
> If you set this flag to an empty string, no project is passed in the request. I tested this with gcloud storage and confirmed that requester pays buckets return the expected error message (“400: Bucket is a requester pays bucket but no user project provided.”). Non-requester pays buckets allow operations as well.

Comment: I'm on Google Cloud SDK 432.0.0 and I am not experiencing this problem.